# How do I "include" code in Java instead of including it in every file?

Tags: java, android

I have the following Java code that allows me to dynamically change the text in my Android app header bar - retrieving the name from Strings.xml.

```
    // Display header title
    headertitle = findViewById(R.id.header_title);
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(getLocalClassName(), "string", getPackageName());
    String header = getResources().getString(id);
    headertitle.setText(header);
```

I don't want to include this in every Activity so how do I create a file that includes this and include / import it on the respective Activities?

Comment: Put it in a (static) method, invoke that method.

Comment: You can create a class with a static method with the code you have and then just call that method..

Comment: Make it a utility method, or make it an instance method of another class and inject an instance of that class, or put it in a base class and inherit from that base class.

Comment: You can't "include" a file like you can in C or C++: because Java deliberately does *NOT* have a "preprocessor".  Nor do any of the .Net languages, for that matter.  What you *CAN* do is put whatever "common definitions/functionality" you want in a class or interface, then "import" that into whatever .java file needs it.  PS: "headerTitle" is much nice looking than "headertitle".

Comment: Thank you all. Looks like i need to do more reading